# change the OpenStack Horizon's login page

Tags: openstack

I need to change the behaviour of the login-page of OpenStack. I am working on an alternatively way to authenticate an user. I use no more name and password. It works on command line but I have to use it also in the graphically part (horizon). 
I should change the action performed when I click the LogIn button, but I can not find where is the implementation of that action: which is the function called by Horizon to authenticate an user?
My aim is to call my new keystone functions to get the token, but I can not find which horizon's function calls keystone.

[UPDATED QUESTION]

the *../horizon/views/auth_forms.py* defines how the login page is defined. Where does its class `Login` is called? I need to modify the code that starts the login page creation

Answer (score 3):

Horizon instantiates an entire class set for keystone interaction.

checkout horizon/openstack_dashboard/api/keystone.py

it mostly uses the python-keystoneclient api set.

You may want to also check out http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/topics/customizing.html

Comment: ok, thank you. If someone is interested too, from that I found that the token is created in /keystoneclient/v2_0/client.py.  The name of the function change according to the openstack version. Anyway the row to search is:  raw_token = function_name(username, password,...)

Comment: How do you know this information? Have you found it by yourself, or read it somewhere in documentation?  thank you

Comment: The documentation has existed for a while and I've been aware of it.  I also have committed code to horizon so I've seen stuff in there as well.

Comment: another problem... I have this error now: Messate is not defined.  It is relative to this line :Messate(root, text=repr(request))     in  api/keystone.py    Do you know what Messate is? I can't find it anywhere in the code

Comment: might be a translation typo on message.  most error messages are translated as part of the django internationalization support.  i8n.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify some files like: horizon/openstack_auth/view.py where **Login** is called.